# displaying a date in a particular format in python

Tags: python, datetime

```
from datetime import date
today = dt.datetime.today().date()

todays_file = 'C:\\Temp\\'+str(today.year)+str(today.month)+str(today.day)+str('.csv')
```

Running:

```
todays_file
```

gives:

```
'C:\\Temp\\2018124.csv'
```

BUT - I need this to be in the format yyyymmdd (not yyyymmd)

So expected output is:

```
'C:\\Temp\\20181204.csv'
```

Similarly, expected output on 3rd feb 2019 is:

```
'C:\\Temp\\20190203.csv'
```

Is there a smart way without using if len(today.day or today.month) = 1: etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

```
d = datetime.datetime.now()
todays_file = 'C:\\Temp\\' + str(d.year) + str("%02d"%d.month) + str("%02d"%d.day) + '.csv'
```

Give:

```
'C:\\Temp\\20181204.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.strftime("%Y%m%d")`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.today().date()

todays_file = r'C:\\Temp\\{}.csv'.format(today.strftime("%Y%m%d"))    
print(todays_file)
```

**Output:**

```
C:\\Temp\\20181204.csv
```

You can also use `str.format` or `fstring` to form your required result string.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date
today_str = date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
file_name = '{}.csv'.format(today_str)
# or in python 3.6+
file_name = f'{today_str}.csv'
```